# È possivel executar 2 querys ao mesmo tempo sem criar uma FUNCTION?

Tags: jsf, jdbc

Tenho um problema onde preciso que ao criar uma nova "locacao" no meu sistema, automaticamente eu preciso que minha tabela de "Quarto" tenha o "id_status" que faz parte de outra tabela mudado.
Isso seria tratavel a nível de banco com uma function, porém minha dúvida é, se é possivel tratar isso a nivel de aplicação.

Meu metodo de incluir na tabela de locação atualmente está assim.

Oque eu queria fazer, era que nesse momento eu pudesse executar outra Query dando update na tabela de Quartos.

```
    public void incluir(Locacao locacao) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = Conexao.conectarNoBancoDeDados();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO locacoes (id_quarto, id_cliente, data_entrada, data_saida, id_statusloc)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    try {
        ps.setLong(1, locacao.getQuarto().getIdQuarto());
        ps.setLong(2, locacao.getCliente().getIdCliente());
        ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(locacao.getDataEntrada().getTime()));
        ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(locacao.getDataSaida().getTime()));
        ps.setLong(5, locacao.getStatusLocacao().getIdStatusLoc());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        Conexao.fecharConexao(conn, ps, null);
    }
}
```